# Restrict access to admin menu pages in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to find a way to limit access to some admin menu pages to specific admins.
So far I have managed to hide the pages from all admins who are not the primary admin but if they enter the URL for that page,they will be directed to that page.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_remove_menu_pages');
function my_remove_menu_pages() {

global $user_ID;

if ( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) && $user_ID !== 1 ) {
remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=settings' );
remove_menu_page( 'plugins.php' );
    //remove_menu_page( 'authorhreview' );
 }
```

}

I have been doing a lot of reading but I can't seem to come up with a solution.
Any help would be awesome.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you thought about using `template_redirect` to redirect specific admins away from the page if they try to access it directly via the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Do not pass a role name to current_user_can(), as this is not guaranteed to work correctly..

See : https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22624

```
function appthemes_check_user_role( $role, $user_id = null ) {
  if ( is_numeric( $user_id ) )
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
  else
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

  if ( empty( $user ) )
    return false;

  return in_array( $role, (array) $user->roles );  
}

//example use for the current user
   if ( appthemes_check_user_role( 'customer' )  
      _e( "You've got access dude!", 'appthemes' );  
   else
      _e( "Sorry man, no luck.", 'appthemes' );  

//example use for a specific user
$user_id = 23;
  if ( appthemes_check_user_role( 'customer', $user_id )
     _e( "You've got access dude!", 'appthemes' );
  else
     _e( "Sorry man, no luck.", 'appthemes' );
```